# apply font on certain portion of text in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, excel-interop

I'am trying to make a portion of text in a textbox bold and the rest of the text stays normal.The textbox is in excel of course I've used this code to create it.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape t1 = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 20, 15, 200, 77);
```

I tried doing that by adding html tags but it seams useless because they just behave as normal text.
I appreciate some help thanks;

Comment: I believe you'll have to use the [characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.characters.aspx) property to select the part of the text you want to make bold.

Comment: Use [Shapes.AddTextEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addtexteffect.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code adds a textbox with text "Text1, Text2" and bolds the second word and sets it's font to "Segoe UI":

```
var t1 = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 20, 15, 200, 77);
t1.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Text1, text2";
t1.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters[8, 5].Font.Bold = MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
t1.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters[8, 5].Font.Name = "Segoe UI";
```